# Executing list of async functions

Tags: javascript

I have an exercise to make a function `executeFunctions` which takes as arguments a list of async functions and an argument, e.g. number.
The functions have to happen one after another, so if `fun1` ends, `fun2` needs to start with the value which was returned from `fun1`.
The problem is that I can't use `async` and `await`. I wanted to do it using `reduce`, but I guess that it wants to execute `const res1` and go further before it returns a value (because of `setTimeout`).
Is there any way to do it without `async` and `await`?

```
const fun1 = function(value) {
   
    return setTimeout(() => value*2, 3000)
}
const fun2 = function(value) {
    
    return setTimeout(() => value*4, 3000)
}
const cb2 = (value) => {
   return value*10

}

const executeFunctions = (funTab, cb) => (n) => {
    const res1= funTab[0](n)
    console.log(res1)
    const resReduce = funTab.reduce((prev,curr) => {
        const res2 = curr(prev)
        return prev+res2
    }, res1)
    return cb(resReduce)

};
executeFunctions([fun1,fun2], cb2)(2)
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `async/await`, other than for the sake of making an excercise purposely difficult and stupidly not real-life-like?

Comment: The reason is that I haven't had `async/await` on my lessons yet, so it would be unacceptable yet. They say it was doable without `async/await`

Comment: I could use Promise, if it's a case there.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case you have to wrap the timeouts inside Promises : `const fun1 = value => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value*2), 3000)`

Comment: If I make something like this, my console.log(res1) returns `Promise {pending}` and nothing happens.

Comment: If the example that you got was using `setTimeout` I'm not sure if it's doable because `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise. The problem with the code above is that `curr(prev)` doesn't return the result but rather a "timer-id" so doing `prev+res2` is meaningless.

Comment: I didn't have to use `setTimeout`. I just had to make async function, but I didn't have any other idea to create it without using `setTimeout`

Comment: We can modify it to something like: `const fun1 = function(value) {   
    return Promise.resolve(value*2);
}` which will make `fun1` async because now it returns a Promise

Comment: Now my result is NaN. It's probably because it doesn't take the value, but it takes whole `Promise { 4 }`. I should change my reduce, shouldn't I?

Comment: @sunny a couple of comments above I explained why the reduce, the way it's currently written, will not work. Fixing the func to return a promise is only one of the problems we have here.

Comment: I tried to change `curr(prev)` to `prev.then((val) => curr(val))`, but it says that `prev.then` is not a function

Comment: @sunny: you have to promisify the init value for `reduce`: `reduce(..., Promise.resolve(x))`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: `my console.log(res1) returns Promise {pending}` --> Of course. Since it's a Promise, you need to do `fun1().then( result => console.log(result) )`. Ideally you would (will) do `const result = await fun1();` but you're not yet allowed to use `await` -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Promise-chaining:

```
const fun1 = function(value) {   
    return Promise.resolve(value * 2); 
}

const fun2 = function(value) {        
    return Promise.resolve(value * 2); 
}

const fun3 = function(value) {   
    return Promise.resolve(value * 2); 
}

const executeFunctions = (funcList) => (n) => {
    let chain = Promise.resolve(n); // initial value
    for (let i = 0; i < funcList.length; i++) {
        chain = chain.then(funcList[i]); // keep chaining
    }
    return chain; // last promise
};

const main = () => {
    // we need to wait for the last promise in order to print the result
    executeFunctions([fun1, fun2, fun3])(2).then(x => console.log('solution is:', x)); 
}

main() // prints: "solution is: 16"
```

or, we can also use a modified version of the suggested reduce solution, by changing the implementation of `executeFunctions` as follows (the rest of the code should remain as in the previous snippet):

```
const executeFunctions = (funcList) => (n) => {
    const init = Promise.resolve(n);
    const res = funcList.reduce((p, c) => {
        return p.then(c)
    }, init);
    return res;
};
```

Comment: that's true, but my function has to work with n functions, so if I have list of 100 functions, it has to work that fun50, takes the result of fun49 etc. The solution you wrote is only for those two functions, I was able to do it, but the problem is when I have n functions.

Comment: I generally have one question - if we use `then` we usually make something like this:  `then(x => console.log(x)`, but you put a function into then (in reduce), so how does the function know, what `value` is? Where does it take the argument from?

Comment: @sunny in the reduce the value is always taken from the output of `prev`. Pay attention to the way the initial value is declared!

Comment: I mean, how does it: `p.then(c)` - how the "c" knows what value it should use itself?
Is it the same if I wrote: `p.then(val => c(val))`?

Comment: @sunny yes it's the same. We can also rewrite one of the last lines to: `executeFunctions([fun1, fun2, fun3])(2).then(console.log)`

Comment: generally it works like this? p.then(function(value) {...}) and the value is what previous Promise returned?